# AutoIt - DllOpen ( "filename" ) failing i.e. It's returning -1

Tags: autoit

I've got AutoIt code as indicated [here](https://gist.github.com/AMonari1/5e99529f70b72207dde5) and I'm encountering issues with DLLOpen() on line 289 of the code i.e it is failing and returning -1.

I've read up [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/DllCall.htm) on what DllOpen() should be returning and I cannot figure out why it is failing.

I've also made sure my Dll file is in the same folder as my .exe file.

In addition I've also specified a specific file path to the Dll file.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're linking to `DllCall` docs but assume you are actually using `DllOpen`. The docs aren't explicit about the search path order, what happens if you specify an absolute path to the DLL? (I know this is not a good solution, but if it works it may mean that `DllOpen` requires the `*.dll` to be either absolute or on the `$PATH`.)

Comment: @cfeduke: thanks for the reply. I've specified different specific paths with no success. What I don't get is that when I run in the SciTE4AutoIt3 editor it works fine but when I convert my au3 file to exe and run it I encounter the problem.

Comment: What converts it to an `*.exe`? If its just an archive (say, PKZip-style self extracting executable archive on the inside that includes an interpreter and your `*.au3` file) then see if there is an option to include other resources with the creation of the `*.exe` and if so, include your `*.dll` as part of the `*.exe` creation. (This is a common pattern for script to exe type containers, though I have no first hand experience with AutoIt.)

Answer (score 0):

If it is working in Skype, it should work compiled.

Dont forget to

```
FileInstall ( "source", "dest" [, flag] )
```

Also dont forget about

```
FileChangeDir ( "path" ) ;Changes the current working directory.
```